# How to properly create XML header (to fill pdf documents in xfdf format) with Delphi using IXMLDOCUMENT

Tags: xml, delphi, xfdf

please I need help to achieve this xml, I have a problme with the third line, this is what I get with my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xfdf xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf/" xml:space="preserve">
  <f xmlns="" href="myExample.pdf">
    <fields>
      <field name="chk01">
        <value>X</value>
      </field>
      <field name="chk02">
        <value>X</value>
      </field>
      <field name="edt11">
        <value>Some text</value>
      </field>
    </fields>
  </f>
</xfdf>
```

**and this is what I need:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xfdf xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf/" xml:space="preserve">    
  <f href="myExample.pdf"/>
  <fields>
    <field name="chk01">
      <value>X</value>
    </field>
    <field name="chk02">
      <value>X</value>
    </field>
    <field name="edt11">
      <value>Some text</value>
    </field>
  </fields>
</xfdf>
```

I dont know how to create the "f" tag like in the second example, notice that it's a little bit different and it closes in the same line and not before the last line like in the first example.

Here is my code:

```
....
Var
  XML : IXMLDOCUMENT;
  RootNode, NodeLevel1, CurNode : IXMLNODE;
Begin
  XML := NewXMLDocument;
  XML.Encoding := 'utf-8';
  XML.Options := [doNodeAutoIndent];

  RootNode := XML.AddChild('xfdf');
  RootNode.Attributes['xmlns']:= 'http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf/';
  RootNode.Attributes['xml:space']:= 'preserve';

  RootNode := XML.DocumentElement.AddChild('f');
  RootNode.Attributes['href']:= 'myExample.pdf';

  NodeLevel1 := RootNode.AddChild('fields');
  CurNode := NodeLevel1.AddChild('field');
  CurNode.Attributes['name'] := 'chk01';
  CurNode := CurNode.AddChild('value');
  CurNode.Text:= 'X';

  CurNode := NodeLevel1.AddChild('field');
  CurNode.Attributes['name'] := 'chk02';
  CurNode := CurNode.AddChild('value');
  CurNode.Text:= 'X';

  CurNode := NodeLevel1.AddChild('field');
  CurNode.Attributes['name'] := 'edt11';
  CurNode := CurNode.AddChild('value');
  CurNode.Text:= 'Some text';

 XMl.SaveToFile('C:\New.fdf');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a bad result because:

1. you are not handling XML namespaces correctly.
2. you are creating the `fields` node as a child of the `f` node instead of as a child of the `xfdf` node.

When a child node is added, it inherits its parent node's namespace unless you explicitly specify a different namespace, and the namespace cannot be changed once assigned.

In your case, your `xfdf` node is not actually being added to the Adobe namespace, **you are faking it!**  The XML engine does not know about the namespace, so the `xfdf` node has a blank namespace, which the `f` child node inherits.  That is why the `f` node ends up with the unwanted `xmlns=""` attribute, so there is no ambiguity as it which namespace child nodes belong to.

To declare a namespace correctly so the XML engine knows about it, you need to use the `IXMLNode.DeclareNamespace()` method instead of using the `IXMLNode.Attributes` property.

You can either:

1. explicitly declare the Adobe namespace on the `xfdf` node after adding it to the document.  The `xfdf` node itself will not be in the namespace (as evident by the `IXMLNode.NamespaceURI` property still being blank), but the namespace can then be explicitly applied when adding the `f` and `fields` child nodes:

   ```pascal
   const
     NsAdobeXfdf = 'http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf/';
   var
     XML: IXMLDocument;
     RootNode, FNode, FieldsNode, FieldNode: IXMLNode;
   begin
     XML := NewXMLDocument;
     XML.Encoding := 'utf-8';
     XML.Options := [doNodeAutoIndent];

     RootNode := XML.AddChild('xfdf'); // <-- xfdf is not in any namespace
     RootNode.DeclareNamespace('', NsAdobeXfdf); // <-- declare the namespace
     RootNode.Attributes['xml:space'] := 'preserve';

     FNode := RootNode.AddChild('f', NsAdobeXfdf); // <-- f is in the Adobe namespace
     FNode.Attributes['href'] := 'myExample.pdf';

     FieldsNode := RootNode.AddChild('fields', NsAdobeXfdf); // <-- fields is in the Adobe namespace

     FieldNode := FieldsNode.AddChild('field'); // <-- inherits namespace from fields
     FieldNode.Attributes['name'] := 'chk01';
     FieldNode.AddChild('value').Text := 'X'; // <-- inherits namespace from field

     FieldNode := FieldsNode.AddChild('field'); // <-- inherits namespace from fields
     FieldNode.Attributes['name'] := 'chk02';
     FieldNode.AddChild('value').Text := 'X'; // <-- inherits namespace from field

     FieldNode := FieldsNode.AddChild('field'); // <-- inherits namespace from fields
     FieldNode.Attributes['name'] := 'edt11';
     FieldNode.AddChild('value').Text := 'Some text'; // <-- inherits namespace from field

     XML.SaveToFile('C:\New.fdf');
   end;
   ```
2. alternatively, declare the Adobe namespace on the `xfdf` node at the time you add that node to the document, and then that node will be in the namespace so the `f` and `fields` child nodes inherit it without you having to call `DeclareNamespace()` manually (`AddChild()` calls it internally for you):

   ```pascal
   const
     NsAdobeXfdf = 'http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf/';
   var
     XML: IXMLDocument;
     RootNode, FNode, FieldsNode, FieldNode: IXMLNode;
   begin
     XML := NewXMLDocument;
     XML.Encoding := 'utf-8';
     XML.Options := [doNodeAutoIndent];

     RootNode := XML.AddChild('xfdf', NsAdobeXfdf); // <-- xfdf is in the Adobe namespace
     RootNode.Attributes['xml:space'] := 'preserve';

     FNode := RootNode.AddChild('f'); // <-- inherits namespace from xfdf
     FNode.Attributes['href'] := 'myExample.pdf';

     FieldsNode := RootNode.AddChild('fields'); // <-- inherits namespace from xfdf

     FieldNode := FieldsNode.AddChild('field'); // <-- inherits namespace from fields
     FieldNode.Attributes['name'] := 'chk01';
     FieldNode.AddChild('value').Text := 'X'; // <-- inherits namespace from field

     FieldNode := FieldsNode.AddChild('field'); // <-- inherits namespace from fields
     FieldNode.Attributes['name'] := 'chk02';
     FieldNode.AddChild('value').Text := 'X'; // <-- inherits namespace from field

     FieldNode := FieldsNode.AddChild('field'); // <-- inherits namespace from fields
     FieldNode.Attributes['name'] := 'edt11';
     FieldNode.AddChild('value').Text := 'Some text'; // <-- inherits namespace from field

     XML.SaveToFile('C:\New.fdf');
   end;
   ```

Either approach will remove the `xmlns=""` attribute on the `f` and `fields` nodes since they belong to a namespace that is declared in the `xfdf` node, and subsequent child nodes will inherit the namespace as expected:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xfdf xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf/" xml:space="preserve">
  <f href="myExample.pdf"/>
  <fields>
    <field name="chk01">
      <value>X</value>
    </field>
    <field name="chk02">
      <value>X</value>
    </field>
    <field name="edt11">
      <value>Some text</value>
    </field>
  </fields>
</xfdf>
```

Comment: wow man, thanks a lot for your time, so clear and well explained. I like the second approach since it's a little less redundant in code, the name space for the child nodes is inherited from the root node and I don't have to specify it again.

Comment: and of course the result is as expected without the unwanted attribute xmlns="" in the node "f" and "fields". Very clear now! :)

Answer (score 1):

you mixed node

f is child xfdf

filds is also child xfdf

solution

```
Var
XML : IXMLDOCUMENT;
fnode, RootNode, NodeLevel1, CurNode : IXMLNODE;
Begin
XML := NewXMLDocument;
XML.Encoding := 'utf-8';
XML.Options := [doNodeAutoIndent];

RootNode := XML.AddChild('xfdf');
RootNode.Attributes['xmlns']:= 'http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf/';
RootNode.Attributes['xml:space']:= 'preserve';

fnode := RootNode.AddChild('f');
fNode.Attributes['href']:= 'myExample.pdf';

NodeLevel1 := RootNode.AddChild('fields');
CurNode := NodeLevel1.AddChild('field');
CurNode.Attributes['name'] := 'chk01';
CurNode := CurNode.AddChild('value');
CurNode.Text:= 'X';

CurNode := NodeLevel1.AddChild('field');
CurNode.Attributes['name'] := 'chk02';
CurNode := CurNode.AddChild('value');
CurNode.Text:= 'X';

CurNode := NodeLevel1.AddChild('field');
CurNode.Attributes['name'] := 'edt11';
CurNode := CurNode.AddChild('value');
CurNode.Text:= 'Some text';

XMl.SaveToFile('C:\tmp\New.fdf');end;
```

Comment: It works! thanks a lot, I have another question for you below :)

Comment: change line RootNode := XML.addChild('xfdf') with
XML.DocumentElement :=  XML.CreateElement('xfdf','http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf/'); RootNode := XML.DocumentElement; and remove add atribute xmlns

Comment: Thanks a lot again, now it's perfect :)

Comment: @ceha: `AddChild()` can be used to create and assign the `DocumentElement` node.  So in the original code, `RootNode` and `XML.DocumentElement` are the same element when `f` is added. `AddChild()` has an overloaded version that accepts a namespace as input.  You do not need to call `CreateElement()` directly.